# At what age should we get a Cockatiel baby at home?

Tags: birds, cockatiels

I want to get a pet bird. I love Cockatiels. I want to get a baby for training. What is the age that the baby must be?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Layna's post however I wouldn't say cockatiels are beginner pets. Each animal is different and has specific needs, you could easily say any pet is not a beginner pet with that logic.

Be thorough with research, we all start somewhere. Mistakes will be made but don't let that discourage you. The most important thing when it comes to taking a baby bird home is to be sure that he/she is fully weaned. This means that she can feed herself independently and not rely on you to spoonfeed her. This is achievable by 8 weeks but sometimes it can take a little longer.

They are very social birds, my little guy always wants to be with the other birds even if they don't approve of him. Birds need to be let our of their cage, I never cage mine unless I leave. Give lots of toys and allow him to forage for his food. You can leave the radio on when you're not around to keep his brain occupied - they are intelligent little animals and must be treated like so.

I'm sure the breeder will give you lots of help but if you have any questions feel free to ask. I will also mention to stay away from any scented fragrances like perfume or candles as well as it harms their lungs. Nonstick cookware must absolutely not be used as the fumes emited are fatal to birds.

**Related Question:** [How/why is Nonstick cookware fatal to birds](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20434/how-why-is-nonstick-cookware-fatal-to-birds)

Answer (score 2):

Cockatiels should not be separated from their parents before they reach 8 weeks. 12 weeks is better, because that is about the time they would separate on their on in the wild: [Cockatiels](http://pets.thenest.com/long-cockatiel-need-stay-mom-11397.html).

But something else to keep in mind: Cockatiels need a LOT of attention when you keep them alone and not as a bonded pair, and you are talking about an animal that will live for about 20 years! They are certainly not beginner-pets.